# How would the MAE of a set of predictions affect further predictions made with that set of predictions

Tags: modeling, mean-absolute-deviation

Suppose I have a model (Model_A) that can predict the net weights of products from an arbitrary input X.

`Weight = Model_A(X)`

Model_A has a mean absolute error of `a`.

---

I have a set of ground truth weights for a bunch of packages with many individual products. My objective is to use `Model_A` to predict the weights of the products in those packages and estimate how much additional weight was added during packaging. And ultimately estimate what percentage of the weight of the package is packaging materials.

How would the mean absolute error of `Model_A` influence my final results. In quantifiable terms. Of course there should be some "summed" error, but how exactly does the composite error get computed.